# Accessing multiple Links using a single toggle button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have 2 buttons(Lights on and Lights off) in my html page to send http request to turn on and off the light. But now,  I don't know how I can send two http requests using a single toggle button. For example: When the toggle button is turned on, it sends a http web request and when it is turned off, it sends another web request.

Goal: When the toggle button is turned on, it sends a request to a smart bulb and turns it on. When the toggle button is turned off, it sends a request to turn off the bulb.

The desired toggle button is

https://codepen.io/juan-carlo-isidro-onciangco/pen/WNrBJWZ

HTML

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="btn-base">
  <input type="checkbox" class="btn-inner">
</div>
```

Check out the full code in the link above

Comment: I see no reason that you can't make a runnable snippet in this case.

Answer (score 1):

check if the class exists first then do your requests based on that

```
btn.addEventListener('click', function() {

    if(btn.classList.contains('turn-on')) {
       btn.classList.remove('turn-on');
       // http request here for turn off
    } else {
       btn.classList.add('turn-on');
       // http request here for turn on
    }
    
    btn.classList.toggle('btn-inner-on');
    bodyWindow.classList.toggle('body-on');
    btnBase.classList.toggle('btn-base-on');
});
```

Comment: But where do you add your both http requests?

Comment: @jo8080 it's right there where I put the comments

Comment: @jo8080 `//http request here` remove the comment and put your request there.

Comment: It is not usual to add event handlers to the class. If the class changes its name, the event will be damaged.

Answer (score 1):

The event in input check. If input checked the turn on, else turn off. Follow as code:

```
const btn = document.querySelector('.btn-inner');
const btnBase = document.querySelector('.btn-base');
const bodyWindow = document.querySelector('body');

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    
    btn.classList.toggle('turn-on');
    btn.classList.toggle('btn-inner-on');
    bodyWindow.classList.toggle('body-on');
    btnBase.classList.toggle('btn-base-on');
  
    if(btn.checked) { 
       //http request here for turn on
       console.log('turn on');
    } else {
       //http request here for turn off
       console.log('turn off');
  }
});
```